# Antec Fusion HTPC case - how to connect volume knob to mainboard?

Tags: audio, case

I have an [Antec Fusion](http://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/Antec/Fusion/) computer case with a [Gigabyte mainboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3474#ov) in it.

The case has an external volume knob, and comes with a remote control.

**Audio:** The case has two cables, one labeled `F_AUDIO`, and one labeled `AC_97`. According to the mainboard manual, there is one `F_AUDIO` connector, and it can deal with either type of cable. I have tried both, but the volume knob doesn't work (I have Windows 7 installed with all drivers).

Can I make the knob work with the mainboard? What would I need to make it work?

<strike>**Remote control**:
What do I need to connect to make the remote control work? I can't see an "IR" cable anywhere.</strike> turns out the remote just needed new batteries and it now just magically works - I assume through the USB connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same case for my HTPC, in black.  Mine came with a remote, but I prefer to use my Microsoft MCE remote, which works with the case's receiver.

If you are using Windows, you need the [Soundgraph iMON software](http://www.soundgraph.com/forums/showthread.php?t=44) installed.  If you do not use Windows, I doubt you will be able to get it working, unless somebody has made Linux drivers for it.

Comment: This looks good - I will get the software and provide feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka: I just remembered, if your case is the v1 silver case, you will have the two line VFD display (mine is a v2 black with LED display). I think the VFD uses different software.  However, as you have an IR receiver on yours, it is probably a v2.

Comment: Both the remote and the sound knob started working fully after installing the Software. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka: You're welcome.  Remember to use the in-software update to get the latest patches, if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions in the manual section "The Display/Volume Control" (bottom of page 4)? It describes how to install the included USB-IR-receiver-connector thingy ;) Please note that there's apparently drivers to install, those should be on a CD included with your case.

For the remote: You need an MCE-compatible remote, this doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: A-ha! I didn't see there was software included with the case - it came to me naked. Thanks for the hint! (The remote is sorted, it was just low on batteries - I think it works somehow through USB. I updated the question accordingly.)